# Pandas boolean indexing w/ Column boolean array

Tags: pandas, boolean

**Dataset**: The name of dataframe I am working on is 'f500'. Here is the
[first five rows in the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMaUr.png)

**Goal**: Select data with only numeric value

**What I've tried**:

1) I tried to use boolean array to filter out the non-numeric values and there was no error.

```
numeric_only_bool = (f500.dtypes != object)
```

[boolean array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmPIB.png)

2) However, when I tried to do indexing with that boolean array, an error occurs.

```
numeric_only = f500[:, numeric_only_bool]
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqcOU.png)

I saw index-wise(row-wise) boolean indexing examples but could not find column-wise boolean indexing. 
Can anyone help how to fix this code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
numeric_only = f500.loc[:, numeric_only_bool]
```

Another soluion with [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
#only numeric
numeric_only = f500.select_dtypes(np.number)
#exclude object columns
numeric_only = f500.select_dtypes(exclude=object)
```